# Wordpress Permalink Redirection working - but still 404 Error - Object not found

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-301, permalinks

I changed my permalink structure from the standard `wittstylepark.at/?p=123` to `wittstylepark.at/postname`. Then I installed the permalink migration plugin from http://www.deanlee.cn/wordpress/permalinks-migration-plugin/. Now the redirection is working fine - when I type in the old url e.g. `wittstylepark.at/?page_id=36` its redirecting to the new url that is e.g. `wittstylepark.at/friseursalon/`.

But now I'm still getting a 404 error message and also if I'm in the wordpress backup working on a page and then press the preview button there is no content to show. I also installed the redirection plugin from http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/redirection/ - but I'm not sure if I'm doing the right thing - because what are working redirections for if the site which they are redirecting to isn't working either.

Comment: i should tell you that newly generated posts and pages are working fine - there are just no old pages - when I deactivate redirection the old url, that is e.g. wittstylepark.at/?page_id=36 is also showing me a 404 error

Comment: are you testing in localhost or hosted server

Comment: i'm testing on a hosted server

Answer (score 1):

I might be too late to answer but actually, you don't need to worry about redirections now. With the latest version of Wordpress, the post permalinks are automatically redirected to the new permalink versions. No need to install any plugins make sure to upgrade your wordpress version and it would work.

Comment: but the host still has to allow rewrite-rules?